# Import/ Exports in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a file called `index.js` that I'm importing other modules into, and exporting them using named exports:

```
import { Card, Icon } from 'some-library';
import ButtonComponent from './Button';

export const Button = ButtonComponent;
```

My question is - how can I export those named imports from `some-library` in the same file without changing their names?

Comment: Did you try exporting them...?

Comment: But I can't do `export const Card = Card` as this name is already taken.

Comment: So just `export Card`;

Comment: This does not work - `Unexpected token, expected {`

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be `export {Card};`

Comment: @Ancinek that's the sort of thing you should include in the question, e.g. "I tried x but got error y".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to import a named export and re-export it with that same name, do this:

```
export { Card, Icon } from 'some-library';
```

If you want to import a default export and re-export it with some specific name, do this:

```
export { default as ButtonComponent } from './Button';
```

Comment: This is just brilliant :)! Thanks!

Comment: Uh, ah. I did this and noticed that the styles has not been imported. I'm using `babel-plugin-import` so the CSS imported along with the module. Is there anyway I can import this css too?

Comment: what styles are you referring to? Is that something exported by either 'some-library' or './Button'? Or is it some standalone css file?

Comment: In this case I'm using `antd` as a UI library. If I do `import { Card } from 'antd'` with aforesaid plugin included in my webpack config, it also imports the styles for the Card that has been included in the library. With the approach above, those styles are not imported anymore. I'm wondering if this is just a plugin issue?

Comment: could be a plugin issue. But if the plugin needs for you to explicitly use `import`, then you can do something like what was mentioned in the comments: `import { Card, Icon } from 'some-library'`, followed by `export { Card, Icon };`

Comment: That's what I've just tried, but them importing those component from my `index.js` file like `import { Card, Icon } from './index.js'` does not work, as those are `undefined` :/

Comment: Sorry, i'm not quite sure how to get it to work in conjunction with that plugin. One thing you could try is importing using one name, and then re-exporting using the name you want. For example: `import { Card as temp } from 'some-library'` and then `export const Card = temp;`

Comment: I've created another file with the imports and exports from that library, and I've imported it in my `index.js`, so the names stays the same. Anyway - you answer was really helpful and made my code cleaner :)